# Windows Edit Start Up Applications C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, api

I was looking at a project that someone wanted done and in order to do it I need to edit Windows' Start Up Programs. I am unsure of where to begin looking. What I really need is just a reference to some Windows API functions that will let me do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Startup programs is just a directory, I don't think there are any specific functions for it. You should be able to create shortcuts inside and that should be it.

```
c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Nikola Smiljanić says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9674408/5987) the Startup area is just a directory with file shortcuts in it. However it is dangerous to use a hardcoded path because this changes with different versions of Windows.

You can get the path to the startup folder with the [`SHGetFolderPath` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) and [`CSIDL_STARTUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx) as a parameter.